# How to validate Parameters against a long set in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am writing a script which will accept a few parameters. I need to validate one parameter that user will have to enter. I use for `[ValidateSet(...)]` feature of `Param` block. 
However, I need to validate this parameter against a very long `hash table`.
Since my hash table is declared after `Param`, How do I validate the user inputs against the keys of that hash table?

Comment: Parameter validation doesn't work that way. If you need to validate against something that's declared after the `Param()` block you need to put the validation code after the block too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) rightly points out that in your case **you need to perform the argument validation *inside* your script, given that the values to validate against aren't yet available at script *declaration* (parsing) time**; using a script block (for simplicity) to demonstrate the technique:

```
& { 
   param(
    [string] $SomeParam
   ) 

   # The hashtable to validate against.
   $hashTable = @{ foo = 1; bar = 2; baz = 3 }

   # Check the -SomeParam argument against the keys of $hashTable.
   if (-not $hashTable.ContainsKey($SomeParam)) { 
     Throw "Invalid -SomeParam argument: $SomeParam"
   }

   # ...

}  bar  # OK, because 'bar' is a key in $hashTable
```